# Invariant subspace of all dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $ \Bbb C,$ and suppose that $\dim(V) = n$. Prove that if
$T \in L(V)$ then for each $k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$, $T$ has an invariant subspace of dimension $k.$

First of all it seems clear to me that we wish to use induction its just not clear to me on what. originally i tried using induction to say it was true when $n=0,1$ trivially assume its true for $1<k<n $ and tried to show it was true for $n$ by looking at the eigenspaces because we know these are invariant but it turns out this is not the right approach the problem is although the may work for some lower values we cant actually say it works for n because we may not have enough eigenvectors to span all of $n$ (it works when the map is diagonalizable only). i did try a non-inductive approach but it was more complicated also appeared to not work.

Comment: You could start by showing it's true when $V$ is a Jordan block.

Comment: i dont know what that means but there should be a simpler approach we haven't learned jordan normal form. also i feel like it should be important that this is over $\Bbb C$ cause its not true over $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Faust But you already learned about eigenvector, eigenvalues, characteristic polynomial and stuff, right?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps upper triangular would work?

Comment: Ara you aware of the fact that any $n\times n$ matrix is similar to a $n\times n$ triangular matrix?

Comment: Yeah i am and i think that might be the correct direction to go in, just working on it now.

Comment: @Faust Yes! An operator $T\in L(V)$ can be represented with a triangular matrix with respect to a certain basis of $V$ iff there exists a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ such that $\forall 0\le k\le n,\,\text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is an invariant subspace of $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints for another approach without triangular form:

The characteristic polynomial of $\;T\;$ has all its roots in $\;\Bbb C\;$, say $\;a_1,...,a_k\;$ . Induction on $\;n\;$ : for $\;n=1\;$ the claim is trivial as the trivial space and the whole space are $\;T\,-$ invariant.

Assume for $\;\dim V<n\;$ and we prove for $\;\dim V=n\;$ . Take the eigenspace $\;V_1\;$ related to the eigenvalue $\;a_1\;$ . Of course, $\;\dim V_1\ge1\;$, so the quotient space $\;V/V_1\;$ has dimension *less* than $\;\dim V=n\;$ . We also have a well-defined linear operator (check all this!)

$$T'\in\mathcal L\left(V/V_1\right)\;,\;\;T'(v+V_1):=Tv+V_1$$

Well, now apply induction and do some mathematics...

Comment: My algebras a lot stronger than my linear algebra so this makes a decent amount of sense (though we never talked about quotient vectors spaces) i wouldn't mind working through this anyway for the learning experience could you possibly tell me the IH in clear terms?

Comment: @Faust By the IH we have within $\;V_1\;$ invariant subspaces of any dimension between zero and $\;\dim V_1\;$ , and the same is true for the space $\;V/V_1\;$ . Now, in this last, if $\;\overline  U\;$ is a $\;T'\,- $ invariant subspace of dimension $\;k\;$,  then (correspondence theorem in groups/rings/linear spaces), its source under the canonical projection is $\;U\;$ , with $\;V_1\le U\le V\;$ , is of dimension $\;k+\dim V_1\;$ and it is $\;T\,-$ invariant...

Comment: [cont.] ...because:
$$T'\overline U\subset\overline U\iff\forall\,u\in U\,,\,\,T'(u+V_1):=Tu+V_i\in\overline U\iff Tu\in U$$
and thus you have invariant subspaces of dimensions $\;0,...,\dim V_1,...,\dim V\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, you thought about using upper triangular matrices. Try proving the following:

> An operator $T\in L(V)$ can be represented with a triangular matrix with respect to a certain basis of $V$ iff there exists a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ such that $\forall 0\le k\le n,\,\text{span}(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ is an invariant subspace of $T$.